# Multiple Update for one Column value within a row

Tags: asp.net, datatable

The code below allow me to add +1 to the row which i select, but my issue is that once its been updated the new value for "Value" isnt accpeted

```
 public void InspireMetrics()
    {
        DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["Metrics"];
        int Desire = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["Value"]);
        int Parti = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[1]["Value"]);
        int Advo = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[2]["Value"]);
        if (SNSIn.Checked)
        {
           table.Rows[0][1] = Desire +1;
           table.Rows[1][1] = Parti +1;
           table.AcceptChanges();
           Databind();
           Chart2.DataSource = table;
        }
        if (TTIn.Checked)
        {
            table.Rows[0][1] = Desire +1;
            table.Rows[2][1] = Advo +1;
            DataBind();
            Chart2.DataSource = table;

        }
        if (MusicIn.Checked)
        {
            table.Rows[0][1] = Desire +1;
            table.Rows[1][1] = Parti +1;
            DataBind();
            Chart2.DataSource = table ;

        }
    }
```

So for example if i select SNS it will update but wont apply the new value so when i want to select music it wont add one towards the newest value

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few statements. This is what you need-

```
     if (TTIn.Checked)
        {
            table.Rows[0][1] = Desire +1;
            table.Rows[2][1] = Advo +1;
            table.AcceptChanges(); //missed
            Chart2.DataSource = table; //first datasource and then databind
            Chart2.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: It should be Chart2.DataBind(). Updated the code. Also mind that if you are checking all the options(SNS, TTIn, MusicIn), `table.Rows[0][1]` will be incremented only by one according to your code.(_may be you already know that_)